# Zend index controller problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

I am trying to create application with Zend framework so
I have created basic application structure with zf tool.

Now when I try to start application with **http://localhost/zendApp/public/index.php**
the default "Welcome to the Zend Framework!" page loads.

But when I type **http://localhost/zendApp/public/** or **http://localhost/zendApp/public/index**  index controller is not invoked, but
rather I get error message:

*Invalid controller specified (zendApp)

```
array (
  'controller' => 'zendApp',
  'action' => 'public',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

- As you see, it is trying to start the controller with the name of application. 
  Also if I create additional actions in index controller and call it with **http://localhost/zendApp/public/index/newaction**
  I get the same error:

  array (
    'controller' => 'zendApp',
    'action' => 'public',
    'index' => 'newaction',
    'module' => 'default',
  )

Can you help me understand why index controller is not invoked?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for your controllers would not include the public folder. Eg UserController would be 
http://localhost/zendApp/user/ not  http://localhost/zendApp/public/user, and your index controller should work on  http://localhost/zendApp/ or  http://localhost/zendApp/index.

Your url rewiter (eg mod_rewrite) should be set up to rewrite all urls to /public/index.php other than static files eg images, css js etc.  see [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter)

Do you have this setup:
"If you are deploying to a "user" site (e.g. http://localhost/~rob), then you need a RewriteBase line in your .htaccess file that looks something like: RewriteBase /~rob/zf-tutorial/public/" from [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand what you mean. But I think that the default for the zend is to access controller exactly through public folder - developers were guessing that when deploying on web server you will put only index.php in public folder and the rest of the application outside of the public folder. But this is not convininet when developing locally for me, so I will use what you said.

Comment: I have found solution for me problem in the first place, when I was reading article http://www.bogartcomputing.com/web-programming-answers/213/a-heavily-corrected-windows-xp-xampp-zend-framework-quickstart-tutorial-revision/ . It seems that I was missing  this:  "line C:\xampp\php\php.ini, uncomment
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll "

Comment: Pretty sure the default structure for Zend is to have your controllers in the application folder, outsite of public, public is just for assets and the index.php which sets up the environment and calls the bootstrap. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/project-structure.project.html